# How to make certain date to be selected in canlndercontrol from cell in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i write the following code it didn't work

Date format in grid-view is like this 2014-01-01

```
Calendar2.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(grid.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text);
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_? Can you please be more specific? Any exception or error message? What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?

Answer (score 0):

if you knw the Date Format you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method

Try This:

```
using System.Globalization;

Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(grid.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text,
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: the day is changing but the year aren't changing

Comment: @user3403112: sorry i did'nt get you. could you please explain your problem with some example.